# Getting cell address of MAXIF result accurately

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is part of the dataset I'm working with.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is get the prevalence of a CBSA in a county, in this example using `Butler County, Alabama`.

This is simple enough with:

```
=MAXIFS($K:$K,$C:$C,$C82,$D:$D,$D82)
```

Which returns `5`.

However, I need to ultimately get the value from column J which should be `Montgomery, AL`.

To do this, I'm trying to get the cell address of the value returned by the `MAXIF`, so it should return `$K$82` and then I could do an `=OFFSET()` from there to get the value from column J.

I can't seem to accurately get the cell address. I've modified my `MAXIF`, based off of [this article](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/961-excel-identify-cell-address.html), to the following:

```
=CELL("address",INDEX($K:$K,MATCH(MAXIFS($K:$K,$C:$C,$C82,$D:$D,$D82),$K:$K,0)))
```

It returns `$K$77`, which is not correct.

I know why it does this: it is finding the first time `5` occurs in `K:K`.

What I'm not sure how to do is prevent it from doing that and just returning the cell address of the `MAXIF` value.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for Cell address when you know what you want to return, If one has Office 365 we can use FILTER:

```
=@FILTER(J:J,(K:K=MAXIFS($K:$K,$C:$C,$C82,$D:$D,$D82))*(C:C=$C82)*(D:D=$D82),"")
```

Comment: Thanks, that is even cleaner than what I was attempting to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to do an `INDEX` or `FILTER`.

Get the code with `=MAXIFS($K:$K,$C:$C,$C82,$D:$D,$D82)`, then `MATCH` on multiple criteria.

For example, `=INDEX(J:J, MATCH(MAXIFS($K:$K,$C:$C,$C82,$D:$D,$D82)&$C82&$D82, K:K&C:C&D:D,0))`

EDIT (thanks @Scott Craner): note that this will be a CSE (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) formula on older versions of Excel